# Is Debug.WriteLine() thread safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Is Debug.WriteLine() thread safe?

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx), it is thread safe. But, in my multithreaded program I am getting some strange output.

For example:

#### Code

```
// these statements are found throughout the program
Debug.WriteLine("Polled database. {0} batch items retrieved.", items.Count());
Debug.WriteLine("Queued batch item: {0}", bm.BatchName);
Debug.WriteLine("Discarded batch item: {0} already queued.", bm.BatchName);
Debug.WriteLine("Creating task for batch item: {0}", bm.BatchName);
Debug.WriteLine("Removed batch item from processing items collection: {0}", bm.BatchName);
Debug.WriteLine("Could not remove batch item from processing items collection: {0}", bm.BatchName);
Debug.WriteLine("Begin Processing: {0}", bm.BatchName);
Debug.WriteLine("End Processing: {0}", bm.BatchName);
```

#### Output

```
"Polled database. 0 batch items retrieved."
"Polled database. 0 batch items retrieved."
"Polled database. 0 batch items retrieved."
"Polled database. 0 batch items retrieved."
"Polled database. 1 batch items retrieved."
"ronnie's batch: Queued batch item: {0}"
"ronnie's batch: Creating task for batch item: {0}"
"Begin Processing: ronnie's batch"
"Polled database. 1 batch items retrieved."
"ronnie's batch: Discarded batch item: {0} already queued."
"End Processing: ronnie's batch"
"ronnie's batch: Removed batch item from processing items collection: {0}"
"Polled database. 0 batch items retrieved."
```

You can see that things start going off the rails with `ronnie's batch: Queued batch item: {0}` If I use string.Format() first, I don't have the problem. What is going on?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you're not calling the overload you think you are. You're calling [`Debug.WriteLine(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x.aspx) which uses the first parameter as the message and the second as a *category*, not a format argument.

The simplest way to fix this is to cast your argument to `object` to force it to use the [`Debug.WriteLine(string, params object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153.aspx) overload:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Queued batch item: {0}", (object) bm.BatchName);
```

A slightly longer-winded approach, but one which is perhaps more object, is to explicitly create the array:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Queued batch item: {0}", new object[] { bm.BatchName });
```

Or (just to keep supplying options :) call `string.Format` explicitly to call the [`Debug.WriteLine(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx) overload:

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Queued batch item: {0}", bm.BatchName));
```

or when you're *just* including the argument directly at the end:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Queued batch item: " + bm.BatchName);
```

Alternatively, you might want to create your own convenience method which *doesn't* have the extra, unhelpful (in your case) overload.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I should have cycled through the overloads!

Comment: Now, that's what I call an answer!

Comment: Does the final option work? I would think you'd want to remove the `{0}` from the literal.

Comment: @dlev: Oops. That's the problem with haste... Thanks Ronnie for editing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread and it's not super relevant to the question, but with newer versions of .NET you can also use the interpolation:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Queued batch item: {bm.BatchName}");
```

Also if you end up here, yes it is threadsafe.  This is not, which I found out the hard way:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Queued batch item: {bm.BatchName}");
```